# Do I increase arrayList when doing list.set(1000, someValue)?

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Do I allocate space for 1000 values when doing like `l1.add(1000, "someText1")`? Or JVM somehow optimize space (I don't know if this possible) to place it tighter?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List l1 = new ArrayList<String>(10);
        l1.add(1000, "someText1"); // do I increased arrayList to 50 values&?
    
        List l2 = new ArrayList<String>(10);
        l2.set(1000, "someText2"); // do I increased arrayList to 50 values&?
    }
}
```

Comment: You've created such a nice small example for your question, but you couldn't be bothered with running that code to see what happens?

Comment: *"I don't know if this possible"* Then **read the documentation**, i.e. the javadoc of [`add(int index, E element)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add-int-E-), with says: *"Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index > size())`"*. Since `index = 1000` and `size() = 0`, you'll get that exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not increasing the size of the `List`, and you are not allocating space for `1000` values. You are causing a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` to be thrown, since `1000` is an invalid index to `set` (or `add`) an element for an empty `List`.

This is mentioned in the Javadoc of both methods:

**void add(int index, E element)**

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range(index < 0 || index > size())

**E set(int index, E element)**

> IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range(index < 0 || index >= size())

`add(int index, E element)` can only add an element immediately after an existing element. Therefore `index` must be <= the original size of the `List`.

`set(int index, E element)` can only replace an existing element of the `List`. Therefore `index` must be < the size of the `List`.

Comment: It should be noted that if the `ArrayList` has more than `1001` elements and is at max capacity, [the list (and thus the backing array) will grow](https://ideone.com/CFTagj).

Comment: @Turing85 that's true, but not the case the OP asked about.